# Recursion issues in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda

I have this `compile` function that is supposed to take a String and then yield an Expression.

This is how `Expression` was defined:

```
data Expression = Name Char | Lambda Char Expression | Apply Expression Expression 
        deriving Show
```

Let's say that the String that the 'compile' function takes is:

```
"\\x.\\y.yx"
```

So, at the end the `compile` function is supposed to yield this as the final Expression:

```
Lambda 'x' (Lambda 'y' (Name 'y') (Name 'x'))
```

This is the `compile` function:

```
compile :: [Char] -> Expression
compile (x:xs) = if [x] == "\\" then Lambda (head xs) (compile (tail xs))
                    else if [x] == "." then compile xs
                    else if null xs then Name x
                    else Name x
```

Currently this function obviates the last part of the Expression (`(Name 'x')`). My question is:

How this function can keep going further with more `Name`s if once I yield a `Name` I can't keep going calling the same function with the rest of the Expression? Since `Expression` was defined like that, if `Expression` is a `Name` it just has a `Name` and no more, there is no expression left on it.

I mean, how can I take every single `Name` that is in `Expression`, 'telling' Haskell that I want to keep looking for `Name`s and not just stop when a single `Name` is found.

I thought that maybe creating another function was a good idea, but I can't figure out how to call that function multiple times. Truth is that I am not really used to recursion in Haskell and I really need some help.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Directly using recursion on `String` for parsing, while doable, is tricky. In your lambda calculus language, handling (nested) parentheses for instance require some care.

If you want to attempt that, at the very least you should look into how [LL parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) work: how to write an LL grammar, how to handle a lookahead symbol, and the basics of formal language theory in general.

If you'd rather learn these "by doing", try playing around with a parser library such as [Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html).

As a minor suggestion: while most papers about the lambda calculus use only single-letter variables and write e.g. "xy" for application, in an implementation you really want longer names for variables, even if it comes at the cost of requiring spaces between applied terms (e.g. "x y"). This makes the parser slightly harder to write but is worth the effort.

Comment: Actually, writing an LL parser with direct recursion isn't hard at all. It's just tedious (Ok there are some corner cases that are tricky, but nothing that would come up when parsing lambda calculus expressions)

Comment: @Cubic It is indeed easy to program (even in imperative languages!) if you understand what a LL grammar is, and a bit of the theory underlying. Yet, it is not something I would expect an average programmer to rediscover on their own without any previous exposure to formal languages. One needs to understand that (for the language at hand) you can write the grammar so that one lookahead token is enough to resolve non-determinism in the productions for each nonterminal.

Comment: Well, you can _often_ get away with one token lookahead. LL(1) doesn't cover all context free grammars after all.